# Adobe Sign for Websites

Tags: website-design, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have an editable PDF I want to put on a WordPress site. When people just try to open the PDF in their browser normally, the signature field is just a text box.  When I make an Adobe Sign request from inside of Acrobat, it converts the signature field to something that you put a physical signature into, and emails them a link.  Is there a way to make a website able to generate a signable document that anyone can request?

Comment: Since I see this got bumped, I just wanted to point out that I never found the solution I was looking for.  But, I was able to establish a workaround that might help others. I was able to use a contact form with a signature box add-on plugin that generated an HTML layout of the form.  This completed form could then be turned into a PDF (if necessary) by using print selection > save as PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [**Adobe Live Cycle**](https://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle.html) for direct mailable PDF forms.

For the average user or small business, it is generally cost prohibitive.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  FYI: Adobe Live Cycle is end of life, Adobe Experience Manager is supposed to be the replacement.

Comment: And thank you for that. Clearly Live Cycle is not something I use, but have looked at.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Adobe Document Cloud. Solution is there and waiting for you.
In short: you will upload PDF to Document Cloud and then embed it to WP site.

Comment: I figured out how to upload to ADC and make a link using Share > Get Link > View File, but the document you get that way still isn't signable like when you share using Adobe Sign via email from inside of Acrobat.

Comment: But you do the same as in e-mail - get pdf that can be downloaded and signed. Online signing is not and cannot be embedable feature more that this.

Comment: I suspect if there was a way to do it, they would have made it doable this way.  The more I think about it, they probably don't let you do this since it would be harder to fake your identity on a publicly accessible form.  Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: You got the point.